# Mysql 10min average data

Tags: mysql, average

I've an mysql table called RawData, and I write value into each minute.
The table look likes ( I've date and time in separated columns):

```
date            time        value
2015-07-17      15:56:04    33.00
2015-07-17      15:57:09    27.00
```

If I want the average data at 18:00 the average should be calculated
with values from 18:00 at 18:09. (By default the mysql dont do that way)

I only to to calculate average with this query:

```
SELECT Date, convert((min(Time) DIV 1000)*1000,time) as Time,Value FROM RawData
Group By Date, Time DIV 1000
```

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Daniel, You need to show us that you have tried to do this yourself.  Do you have some SQL that isnt working.  Have you tried?

Comment: I've tried with:

    SELECT Date, convert((min(Time) DIV 1000)*1000,time) as Time,Value FROM RawData
    Group By Date, Time DIV 1000

Comment: Look up the AVG sql keyword

Comment: what would you like your output to look like as i have no clue what that syntax means and can't read your mind. forgetting the raw data, how do you want to call the select statement with data (not the select stmt you showed), and what is the result set from that? Are you calling `something` with date and 18:00, are you calling something with 18:00 and 18:09? what?

Comment: Maybe you want it for every date available at 10 minute increments. maybe that data is not present in your table and a left join is required. the question needs serious improvement for anyone to do it without 9 questions. It should already be in your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `time` is in a time format, then the following should do what you want:

```
select date, maketime(hour(time), 10 * floor(minute(time)/10), 0) as time,
       avg(value)
from rawdata 
group by date,  maketime(hour(time), 10 * floor(minute(time)/10), 0)
order by date, time;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You save my life.